# JSF Primefaces form errors after failed validation

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf, primefaces

I am new to JSF/Java in general but have been trying to solve this for a few days now.

I have a form which gets stuck on validation.  When all the entries are valid, it all works well.  The minute I break validation (such as don't provide a required value), then the form gets stuck.  One thing that happens is I cant correct the invalid entry it seems and repost.  Also, where I had a cascading ajax call of a selectOneMenu, that suddenly starts failing...even though this is not the invalidated part of the form.

I notice that the cascading drop down seems to be throwing null pointer exceptions in its overridden equals method.

I am at a loss.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
<ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="content">
        <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/>  

        <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status"   
                draggable="false" closable="false">  
        <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />  
</p:dialog>
        <h:form id="form">
            <p:panel id="panel"
                header="Please ensure your personal details are accurate"
                style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                <p:messages id="msgs" />
                <h:outputText
                    value="Please ensure your personal details are up to date and accurate within the Admin Direct system. Please note that this application only supports GMD customers, so unless you are within GMD, or are a user of the GMD Admin Direct service, please do not enter your details or attempt to use the application for administrative support." />
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellpadding="5" id="grid">

                    <h:outputText value="First Name:" style="font-weight:bold" />
                    <p:inputText id="firstName"
                        value="#{personalDetailsBean.user.firstName}" 
                        requiredMessage="First name is required..." style="width:250px" />
                    <p:message id="firstNameMessage" for="firstName" />

                    <h:outputText value="Last Name:" style="font-weight:bold" />
                    <p:inputText id="lastName"
                        value="#{personalDetailsBean.user.lastName}" 
                        requiredMessage="Last name is required..." style="width:250px" />
                    <p:message id="lastNameMessage" for="lastName" />

                    <h:outputText value="Select Function:" style="font-weight:bold" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="functions"
                        value="#{personalDetailsBean.user.function}" 
                        style="width:250px">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Function" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{personalDetailsBean.functions}" var="func"
                            itemLabel="#{func.functionName}" itemValue="#{func}" />
                        <f:converter converterId="functionConverter" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:message id="functionMessage" for="functions" />

                    <h:outputText value="Select Site" style="font-weight:bold" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="sites"
                        value="#{personalDetailsBean.user.site}" 
                        style="width:250px">
                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Site" itemValue="" />
                        <f:selectItems value="#{personalDetailsBean.sites}" var="sit"
                            itemLabel="#{sit.siteName}" itemValue="#{sit}" />
                        <f:converter converterId="siteConverter" />
                        <p:ajax update="region" event="change" process="@this"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
                    <p:message id="siteMessage" for="sites" />

                    <h:outputText value="Region" style="font-weight:bold" />
                    <h:outputText id="region"
                        value="#{personalDetailsBean.user.site.region.regionName}" />
                    <p:message id="regionMessage" for="region" />

                    <h:outputText value="Email" style="font-weight:bold" />
                    <p:inputText id="email" value="#{personalDetailsBean.user.email}"
                        required="true"
                        validatorMessage="Invalid email address format"
                        style="width:250px">
                    <f:validateRegex
                       pattern="[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]@[\w\.-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\.]*[a-zA-Z]" />
                        <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:message id="emailMessage" for="email" />
                </h:panelGrid>
                <p:separator />
                <p:commandButton value="Save" id="btnSubmit" actionListener="#{personalDetailsBean.saveUser}" process="@all" update="panel" />
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

any advice greatly appreciated.

Regards

SM

Comment: Hi, I seem to have fixed it without understanding why.  My Site class had an override of equals but no override of the hashcode...I got eclipse to override the hashcode, and now it all works.  Would be good to know why it all works until validation fails.

Comment: With out your java code it would be difficult to see why that worked. Is there a reason you are using an ajax submit and not a standard form submit? try putting ajax="false" on your p:commandButton and remove the process="@all" - this will do a form submit regardless and re-render everything.